# Clamscan -ri Bash Get Filename

Tags: command-line, bash, clamav

How can I get the file path of the returned infected files list from a `clamscan -ri`?

right now I am seeing this:

```
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/HB006_Hyalobarrier-Product-training-MASTER-10-07-15.ppt: Doc.Exploit.CVE_2015_2341 FOUND
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/HB006_Hyalobarrier-Product-training-MASTER-10-07-15.ppt: copied to '/folder/infections//HB006_Hyalobarrier-Product-training-MASTER-10-07-15.ppt'
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Tech003_HA_HYAFF_technology_MASTER_presentation_RevB.ppt: Doc.Exploit.CVE_2015_2341 FOUND
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Tech003_HA_HYAFF_technology_MASTER_presentation_RevB.ppt: copied to '/folder/infections//Tech003_HA_HYAFF_technology_MASTER_presentation_RevB.ppt'
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/HM006_Hyalomatrix_PA_product_overview_training_RevB.ppt: Doc.Exploit.CVE_2015_2341 FOUND
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/HM006_Hyalomatrix_PA_product_overview_training_RevB.ppt: copied to '/folder/infections//HM006_Hyalomatrix_PA_product_overview_training_RevB.ppt'
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/HG010_Hyaloglide_product_overview_training_RevC.ppt: Doc.Exploit.CVE_2015_2341 FOUND
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/HG010_Hyaloglide_product_overview_training_RevC.ppt: copied to '/folder/infections//HG010_Hyaloglide_product_overview_training_RevC.ppt'
```

what I'd like is the file path only.  for instance `/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/HB006_Hyalobarrier-Product-training-MASTER-10-07-15.ppt`

Maybe a simple `sed` command to grab everything before the :?  I don't know the pattern I should use tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using `awk` + `readarray`;

To process the output of `clamscan -ri`:

```
clamscan -ri | awk -F ':' '/FOUND/ {print $1}'
```

- `-F ':'`: sets `awk`'s field separator to `:`;
- `/FOUND/`: pattern; executes the following action only if the record matches the `FOUND` string;
- `{print $1}`: prints the first field;

To read the processed output of `clamscan -ti` into an array `$x`:

```
mapfile -t x < <(clamscan -ri | awk -F ':' '/FOUND/ {print $1}')
```

- `-t`: removes the trailing newline at the end of each line before reading it into the array;
- `< <(clamscan -ri | awk -F ':' '/FOUND/ {print $1}')`: redirects the output of the process substitution `<(clamscan -ri | awk -F ':' '/FOUND/ {print $1}')` to `readarray`'s `stdin`

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/tmp$ cat infile
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/HB006_Hyalobarrier-Product-training-MASTER-10-07-15.ppt: Doc.Exploit.CVE_2015_2341 FOUND
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/HB006_Hyalobarrier-Product-training-MASTER-10-07-15.ppt: copied to '/folder/infections//HB006_Hyalobarrier-Product-training-MASTER-10-07-15.ppt'
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Tech003_HA_HYAFF_technology_MASTER_presentation_RevB.ppt: Doc.Exploit.CVE_2015_2341 FOUND
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Tech003_HA_HYAFF_technology_MASTER_presentation_RevB.ppt: copied to '/folder/infections//Tech003_HA_HYAFF_technology_MASTER_presentation_RevB.ppt'
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/HM006_Hyalomatrix_PA_product_overview_training_RevB.ppt: Doc.Exploit.CVE_2015_2341 FOUND
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/HM006_Hyalomatrix_PA_product_overview_training_RevB.ppt: copied to '/folder/infections//HM006_Hyalomatrix_PA_product_overview_training_RevB.ppt'
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/HG010_Hyaloglide_product_overview_training_RevC.ppt: Doc.Exploit.CVE_2015_2341 FOUND
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/HG010_Hyaloglide_product_overview_training_RevC.ppt: copied to '/folder/infections//HG010_Hyaloglide_product_overview_training_RevC.ppt'
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/tmp$ cat infile | awk -F ':' '/FOUND/ {print $1}'
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/HB006_Hyalobarrier-Product-training-MASTER-10-07-15.ppt
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Tech003_HA_HYAFF_technology_MASTER_presentation_RevB.ppt
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/HM006_Hyalomatrix_PA_product_overview_training_RevB.ppt
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/HG010_Hyaloglide_product_overview_training_RevC.ppt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/tmp$ mapfile -t x < <(awk -F ':' '/FOUND/ {print $1}' infile)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/tmp$ echo "${x[@]}"
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/HB006_Hyalobarrier-Product-training-MASTER-10-07-15.ppt /home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Tech003_HA_HYAFF_technology_MASTER_presentation_RevB.ppt /home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/HM006_Hyalomatrix_PA_product_overview_training_RevB.ppt /home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/HG010_Hyaloglide_product_overview_training_RevC.ppt
```

Comment: Tried
    cl_scan=$(clamscan -ri | awk -F ':' '/FOUND/ {print $1}')
    for f in "${cl_scan[@]}"
    do
     echo $f
    done
to no avail, also tried the mapfile

Comment: @Kevin Did you copy paste the command? If you did then the command should have rather been `cl_scan=$(clamscan -ri | awk -F ':' '/FOUND/ {print $1}'); for f in "${cl_scan[@]}"; do echo "$f"; done`. if this doesn't work please add the full output of `clamscan -ri` to your question

Comment: yea, it was just missing the path to scan.   thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$ clamscan -ri | sed -n '/FOUND/s/: .*//p'
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/HB006_Hyalobarrier-Product-training-MASTER-10-07-15.ppt
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Tech003_HA_HYAFF_technology_MASTER_presentation_RevB.ppt
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/HM006_Hyalomatrix_PA_product_overview_training_RevB.ppt
/home/folder/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/HG010_Hyaloglide_product_overview_training_RevC.ppt
```

#### How it works

Each file appears on two lines of the input.  To avoid duplicates, we need to select just one of those lines.  This code selects the first appearance, the one with the word `FOUND` at the end of the line.  It then removes everything after the `:` and prints the line.

In more detail:

- `-n`

  This tells sed not to print anything unless we explicitly ask it to.
- `/FOUND/ s/: .*//p`

  This selects the lines that contain the word `FOUND`.  The substitute command, `s/: .*//`, removes everything after the colon-space.  The suffix `p` tells sed to print these lines.

#### Making the output into a bash array

To make a bash array of the file names:

```
IFS=$'\n' cl_scan=($(clamscan -ri | sed -n '/FOUND/s/: .*//p'))
```

Because we set `IFS=$'\n'`, this will work even for file names that contain spaces or tabs.  This will not work for file names that contain newlines or colon-space.

To verify that the array is as desired, run:

```
$ declare -p cl_scan
declare -a cl_scan='([0]="/home/folder/public html/wp content/uploads/2015/07/HB006 Hyalobarrier Product training MASTER 10 07 15.ppt" [1]="/home/folder/public html/wp content/uploads/2015/02/Tech003 HA HYAFF technology MASTER presentation RevB.ppt" [2]="/home/folder/public html/wp content/uploads/2015/02/HM006 Hyalomatrix PA product overview training RevB.ppt" [3]="/home/folder/public html/wp content/uploads/2014/10/HG010 Hyaloglide product overview training RevC.ppt")'
```

Comment: so, `cl_scan=$(clamscan -ri /home/*/public_html | sed -n '/FOUND/s/: .*//p');` would be an array of the paths?  I just echo'd it, and it looked like it was all one string, but space seperated

Comment: think I got it `cl_arr=(${cl_scan// / });` seems to do the trick :)    Appreceite the help!

Comment: @Kevin I added a section to the answer dealing with arrays.

Comment: aye, tried that, and got `cat: clam: no such file...` tried it with clamscan as welll

Comment: ah, but that doesnt get me the results from clamscan :)

Comment: @Kevin Oops.  Typo corrected.